# Setting Cell Formula within a Loop

Tags: java, apache-poi

How would I be able to set the Cell's formula within a loop in Apache POI?

Here's an information to support my question:

Cell C1 has the formula of SUM(C6:C7) which can be done by simply hard coding the formula myCell.setCellFormula("SUM(C6:C7)").
On the other hand:

This is my desired output. I want to set a formula on Cells C1, D1, and E1 for example. How can this be done within a loop?

Why would I want it within a loop?
- Hard-coding would be tiresome. 3 cells are just and example. Currently I have hundreds of cells waiting for their formula.
- Row count are not specified, it will be based on the number of rows created by the program.

What I have done?
- Googled.
- Searched for similar question.

i tried like so

```
int lastRownum = dataMap.size();
int i = 1;
char c;

for(c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++){
System.out.println();
sheet.createRow(lastRownum + 1).createCell(i).setCellFormula("SUM('"+c+"'4:'"+c+"''"+lastRownum+"')");
i++;
}
```

i expected the output as get the sum of each column of the sheet

Comment: Its not quite clear what exactly you want to achieve as well as whats wrong with that code

Comment: `sheet.createRow(lastRownum + 1).createCell(i).setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA).setCellFormula("SUM('"+c+"'4:'"+c+"''"+lastRownum+"')");`

Comment: Have a look at [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html). Using this class a cell reference can be created using row and column numeric. The `formatAsString` method then gets a string like `A1`. Also this class has `convertNumToColString` method.